# What difference between <%%> and <%!%>

Tags: jsp, jsp-tags

I try to find that in JSP people use several different tags like `<% %>` and`<%! %>` when add Java code to page, but can anyone tell me what is the main difference between this two tags.

Thanks.

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsp/info and http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/code-convention-138726.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, there are a number of different jsp scripting elements, each with different usages. These are:

- `<% %>`: Scriptlets

  - Evaluates a Java expression. Does not display any result in the HTML produced. Variables declared have only local scope, so cannot be accessed from elsewhere in the .jsp
- `<%! %>` : Declarations

  - Allows the declaration of methods or variables, which can then be accessed elsewhere in the .jsp
- `<%@ %>`: Directives

  - Specifies page-dependent attributes, such as the scripting language used, or "include" statements
- `<%= %>`: Expressions

  - Evaluates a Java expression. Inserts the result (as a string) into the HTML in the .jsp
- `<%-- --%>`: Comments

  - JSP comment tags. These will not show up in the page source, unlike HTML comments

For full documentation, see: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14099_19/web.1012/b14014/genlovw.htm

Comment: RoryB, thnx for your answer

Answer (score 1):

`<!% %>` Tag is declare java method(function) in JSP page

`<% %>` Tag is write Statement in JSP page

JSP look like a java class

over!

Comment: thanx, i have problem with creating method inside <% %> tags, but now all is ok.

Comment: `<% %>` tags don't write a statement to the jsp: `<%= %>` tags do that

Answer (score 0):

Scriptlets are blocks of code delimited by <% and %>

Declarations are delimited by <%! and %>

you can refer this link it
http://inside.mines.edu/~crader/cs443/Chapters/Chap10.html